# Duda sobre incremento a una variable desde una condicional antes de llamar a una función - Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, condiciones, función-personalizada, operador-incremento

quisiera saber por qué parte de este código funciona haciendo lo que espero que es contar la cantidad de veces que se ejecuta en el if la parte que calcula la persistencia(no estoy seguro si se llama así en español o es real el término):

```
let contar = 0;

persistence = (param) => {
    contar = 0;

    if (param !== undefined && param > 0) {
        let num = param;

        let numString = num.toString();

        let arreglo = numString.split("");
        let arregloNum = arreglo.map(Number);

        if (arregloNum.length >= 2) {
            let calc = arregloNum.reduce((p, c) => p * c);
            persistence(calc);
            contar++;
            console.log(calc);
            return contar;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

console.log(persistence(39));
console.log(persistence(4));
console.log(persistence(25));
console.log(persistence(999));
```

Pero si pongo `contar++` antes de `persistence(calc);` el contador se queda en 0. Aquí el código de cómo no funciona correctamente:

```
let contar = 0;

persistence = (param) => {
    contar = 0;

    if (param !== undefined && param > 0) {
        let num = param;

        let numString = num.toString();

        let arreglo = numString.split("");
        let arregloNum = arreglo.map(Number);

        if (arregloNum.length >= 2) {
            let calc = arregloNum.reduce((p, c) => p * c);
            contar++;
            persistence(calc);
            console.log(calc);
            return contar;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

console.log(persistence(39));
console.log(persistence(4));
console.log(persistence(25));
console.log(persistence(999));
```

¿Alguien me puede explicar a qué se debe esto? Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno paso a explicarte la secuencia de ejecución de tus funciones, espero esto te ayude (el debug manual se encuentra en los comentarios del código al final, leelos por favor.):

```
let contar = 0;

persistence = (param) => {
    contar = 0;

    if (param !== undefined && param > 0) {
        let num = param;

        let numString = num.toString();

        let arreglo = numString.split("");
        let arregloNum = arreglo.map(Number);

        if (arregloNum.length >= 2) {
            let calc = arregloNum.reduce((p, c) => p * c);
            persistence(calc);
            contar++;
            console.log(calc);
            return contar;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

console.log(persistence(39));
// Ejecución manual.
// entramos a persistence 39 ->
// contar = 0, num = 39, numString = '39', arreglo = ['3','9'], arregloNum = [3,9], calc = 27, llamamos a persistence(27) (vamos a movernos a esta función)

// entramos a persistence 27 ->
// contar = 0, num = 27, numString = '27', arreglo = ['2','7'], arregloNum = [2,7], calc = 14, llamamos a persistence(14) (vamos a movernos a esta función)

// entramos a persistence 14 ->
// contar = 0, num = 14, numString = '14', arreglo = ['1','4'], arregloNum = [1,4], calc = 4, llamamos a persistence(4) (vamos a movernos a esta función)

// entramos a persistence 4 ->
// contar = 0 (OJO EN ESTA PARTE acá devuelves contar a 0 ANTES de haberla incrementado) retornamos 0 ya que no cumple las condiciones, nos regresamos a la función persistence(14) que nos invoco

// regresamos persistence 14 ->
// contar = 1, console.log(4) retornamos  contar (contar = 1 ult incremento), y volvemos a la función que nos invoco persistence 27.

// regresamos persistence 27 ->
// contar = 2, console.log(14) retornamos contar (contar = 2 ult incremento), y volvemos a la función que nos invoco persistence 39.

// regresamos persistence 39 ->
// contar = 3, console.log(27) retornamos contar (contar = 3 ult incremento), y volvemos a la linea de código console.log(persistence(39));.

// como persistence(39) retorno 3 entonces en consola muestra 3
```

Ahora correremos tu segundo algoritmo manualmente de la siguiente manera.

```
let contar = 0;

persistence = (param) => {
    contar = 0;

    if (param !== undefined && param > 0) {
        let num = param;

        let numString = num.toString();

        let arreglo = numString.split("");
        let arregloNum = arreglo.map(Number);

        if (arregloNum.length >= 2) {
            let calc = arregloNum.reduce((p, c) => p * c);
            contar++;
            persistence(calc);
            console.log(calc);
            return contar;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

console.log(persistence(39));
// Ejecución manual.
// entramos a persistence 39 ->
// contar = 0, num = 39, numString = '39', arreglo = ['3','9'], arregloNum = [3,9], calc = 27, contar = 1, llamamos a persistence(27) (vamos a movernos a esta función)

// entramos a persistence 27 ->
// contar = 0, num = 27, numString = '27', arreglo = ['2','7'], arregloNum = [2,7], calc = 14, contar = 1, llamamos a persistence(14) (vamos a movernos a esta función)

// entramos a persistence 14 ->
// contar = 0, num = 14, numString = '14', arreglo = ['1','4'], arregloNum = [1,4], calc = 4, contar = 1, llamamos a persistence(4) (vamos a movernos a esta función)

// entramos a persistence 4 ->
// contar = 0 (OJO EN ESTA PARTE acá devuelves contar a 0 DESPUÉS de haberla incrementado anteriormente) retornamos 0 ya que no cumple las condiciones, nos regresamos a la función persistence(14) que nos invoco

// regresamos persistence 14 ->
// console.log(4) retornamos contar (= 0) (que persistence(4) lo dejo en 0), y volvemos a la función que nos invoco persistence 27.

// regresamos persistence 27 ->
// console.log(14) retornamos contar (= 0) que persistence(4) lo dejo en 0), y volvemos a la función que nos invoco persistence 39.

// regresamos persistence 39 ->
// console.log(27) retornamos contar (= 0) que persistence(4) lo dejo en 0), y volvemos a la linea de código console.log(persistence(39));.

// como persistence(39) retorno 0 entonces en consola muestra 0
```

Entonces que paso? bueno lo único que estas haciendo mal es manejar la variable global `contar`.

 Ahora para que declaras `contar` como **variable global** si vas a usarla como **variable local** (ya que la inicializas siempre la entrar a la función `pesistence`) ahora si quieres conservar el valor adecuado del contador lo mejor es que lo envíes como parámetro de la función.

 Hay que tener cuidado cuando se usas **variables** globales, tu estas esperando un determinado valor de esa **variable** pero que ya ha sido modificado por otra función luego de que la función principal ya realizo sus cambios entonces ya tienes una valor "basura" en esa variable, creo que esto puede entrar en el tema de semáforos cuando se accede al mismo recurso compartido, en este caso tu recurso compartido es la **variable** `contar`, mmmmm bueno tal vez el tema sea otro, pero espero haberte ayudado aclarar tu duda, suerte.

Luego, tu función podría quedar de la siguiente manera si decides pasar el contador como parte de un parámetro, donde por defecto ponemos el contador en 0 cuando no enviamos el parámetro, entonces continuamos llamando a `persistence(39)` te va dar un contador inicializado en 0 (`contar`) por defecto como segundo parámetro, que luego estaremos enviado a las siguientes llamadas de función `persistence`

```
persistence = (param, contar = 0) => {
    if (param !== undefined && param > 0) {
        let num = param;

        let numString = num.toString();

        let arreglo = numString.split("");
        let arregloNum = arreglo.map(Number);
        if (arregloNum.length >= 2) {
            let calc = arregloNum.reduce((p, c) => p * c);
            contar = persistence(calc, contar + 1);
            console.log(calc);
        }
        return contar;
    } else {
        return contar;
    }
};
console.log(39) // imprime 3 finalmente
```